# Turtle Beach Headset Chat Volume Wheel on Windows

Tags: windows, audio, headset

I have this headset http://www.turtlebeach.com/product-detail/headsets-legacy/ear-force-x11/235

I am using it with a Windows 8.1 PC using digital audio out on my motherboard (no dedicated sound card).

The cable has 2 volume wheels labelled "Game" and "Chat". I would like to be able to control, say Google Hangouts or Skype volume with the chat wheel, and all other audio with the other wheel. Is this possible?

The closest thing I can find is "Communications Device" vs "Device" under the Sound control panel in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If the product you linked in exactly what you have you will not be able to use the chat wheel for controlling audio.

This wheel is used when you have the headset connected together with an Xbox360 controller. This headset mixes the Xbox360 sounds with the sounds provided from the controller, which is usually chat from the headset jack. It will manage the volume of the chat coming from the controller. The other wheel "game" will control the overall volume of the audio coming from the audio in(green connector). Which in your case on a PC is 'all' sounds.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you would need either,

A) An audio device that has multiple outputs in 3.5mm style

Or

B) Multiple audio devices (ex: onboard audio + internal audio card/external audio device

Or

C) Software such as Virtual Audio Cable